# How to create a string of key-value pair object from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects coming from the backend like below

```
  const paramData = [
    {id: "search_type", value: "All items", required: true},
    {id: "time_period", value: "Week", required: false},
    {id: "user_type", value: "All Users", required: false},
    {id: "question_type", value: "Multiple questions", required: true},
  ];
```

I would like to extract the values of only the `id` and the `value` key of each object and make something like below

```
  const extractedData = "{\"search_type\": \"All items\", \"time_period\": \"Week\", \"user_type\": \"All Users\", \"question_type\": \"Multiple questions\"}";
```

What would be the optimum way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce;

```
  const extractedData = paramData.reduce((obj, item) => {
     obj[item.id] = item.value
     return obj
   }, {})
```

Please see detailed description [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
I also strongly recommend `map` and `filter`. With `reduce`, they are 3 stars of array

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to *ilkerkaran*'s one could be:

```js
const paramData = [{
  id: "search_type",
  value: "All items",
  required: true
}, {
  id: "time_period",
  value: "Week",
  required: false
}, {
  id: "user_type",
  value: "All Users",
  required: false
}, {
  id: "question_type",
  value: "Multiple questions",
  required: true
},];

var extractedData = "";

for (var i in paramData) {
  extractedData += `"${paramData[i].id}": "${paramData[i].value}", `;
}

extractedData = `{${extractedData.slice(0, -2)}}`;

console.log(extractedData);
```